# thymeleaf using p tag send GET request to server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The below is my sample code that I try to send request to server by using `<p>` element. But the method getUserName under URL mapping "admin/home/username" didn't work at all. Could anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

example.html

```
<p th:text="@{/admin/home/username">Unknow User</p>
```

example.java (Controller)

```
@RequestMapping(value ={"admin/home/username", "/username"})
@ResponseBody
public String getUserName(){.....}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ annotation is just for printing relative or absolute URIs. So you can't expect it to reach your controller. Instead of th:text, you need to add userName from your controller which printed that specific page.

Eg:

```
mav.addObject("userName",userName);
```

and in your html

```
<p th:text="${username}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Sahin Yanlik 
But it works fine with img tag but it just doesn't work with p tag. 
<img  th:src="@{/admin/home/image/user-profile}">

Comment: yes because src: tag knows it is static file so it can show. But p tag doesn't have this kind of ability. It just expect you want to show text on screen.